# Python convert dictionary to argparse

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

Right now, I have a script that can accept command line arguments using argparse. For example, like this:

```py
#foo.py
def function_with_args(optional_args=None):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  # add some arguments
  args = parser.parse_args(optional_args)
  # do something with args
```

However, I'd like to be able to use this function with a dictionary instead, for example with something like this:

```py
def function_using_dict(**kwargs):
  # define parser and add some arguments
  args = parser.parse_dict_args(kwargs)
  # everything else is the same
```

Note that I have a lot of arguments with default values in argparse which I'd like to use, so the following wouldn't work:

```
def function_no_default_args(**kwargs):
  args = kwargs # not using default values that we add to the parser!
```

Comment: Do you just want to inject a set of values into a `Namespace` object? You can do that directly: `args = argparse.Namespace(**kwargs)`. The point of `parse_args` is to convert a list of strings into a `Namespace` object; it's not clear what is in your `dict` or what you would want `argparse` to do with it otherwise.

Comment: That would be a good idea. Is there a way to get the default values too with the parser, something like `ns = parser.parse_args([]); ns.update(kwargs)`? (but the problem is that namespace doesn't seem to have an 'update' function)

Comment: You can do `parser.parse_args([], ns)`, though `parse_args` will not take into account the values already in `ns`. If you want your `kwargs` to take precedence over `parse_args`, you can do something like `n = Namespace(**{ **vars(p.parse_args([])), **kwargs})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argparse.Namespace` is a relatively simple object subclass, with most of its code devoted to displaying the attributes (as `print(args)` shows).  Internally `parse_args` uses `get_attr` and `set_attr` to access the namespace, minimizing the assumptions about attributes names.

When using subparsers, the subparser starts with a 'blank' namespace, and uses the following code to copy its values to the main namespace.

```
    # In case this subparser defines new defaults, we parse them
    # in a new namespace object and then update the original
    # namespace for the relevant parts.
    subnamespace, arg_strings = parser.parse_known_args(arg_strings, None)
    for key, value in vars(subnamespace).items():
        setattr(namespace, key, value)
```

Originally the main namespace was passed to the subparser, eg.  `parser.parse_known_args(arg_strings, namespace)`, but the current version lets the subparser defaults take priority.

Handling defaults is a bit complicated.  If you don't have any required arguments then

```
 args = parser.parse_args([])
```

will set all the defaults.  Or you could look at the start of `parse.parse_known_args` to see how defaults are inserted into the namespace at the start of parsing.  Just beware that there's an added step at the end of parsing that runs remaining defaults through their respective `type` functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert the result of `parse_args` into a `dict`, you can probably just do this:

```py
kwargs = vars(args)
```

After your comment, I thought about it. Going to go with your existing function.

```py
#foo.py
def function_with_args_and_default_kwargs(optional_args=None, **kwargs):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  # add some arguments
  # add the other arguments
  for k, v in kwargs.items():
    parser.add_argument('--' + k, default=v)
  args = parser.parse_args(optional_args)
  # do something with args
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the quick reply. I meant to do the other way around. I have a dictionary, but I still want to be able to "parse" it with argparse so I can get the arguments with default values as well.

Comment: Wouldn't you want descriptions, or did you just want the arguments (assuming all strings) to have a default value?

Comment: You're right, I don't need to have the argparse descriptions for my arguments in this case. I just want them to have a default value which I already specified with argparse.

Comment: Had to make a few fixes, but I think iterating through the `kwargs` and adding them to your parser would work, although you can't know the description, etc.